# how to access objects that are returned from a function

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

New to `javascript` and learning about objects on `freeCodeCamp`. I have the function below that returns an object. I would like to be able to access `totalOutboxes` which holds an `integer` I get back outside of the function. I would like to do something like this

`myTotal = result.totalOutboxes`

where the variable `myTotal` will hold an `integer` that I get back. For example, it will hold 10. How can I go about doing this? A steer in the right direction would be great!

```
const getTotalResponses = () => {
const result = {
// This holds actual total outboxes
             totalOutboxes,
             conversations
        }
        return result;
    };
```

Comment: FYI, `function() => {` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for telling me. I fixed it above.

Comment: If `result` in `myTotal = result.totalOutboxes` is the return value of the function (i.e. `const result = getTotalResponses()`) then it works just like that. Accessing an object always works the same way, not matter how it was created or where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain the retuned object by assigning it to a variable and get the `totalOutboxes` property:

```js
let totalOutboxes = 10,
  conversations = 99;

const getTotalResponses = () => {
  const result = {
    totalOutboxes,
    conversations
  }
  return result;
};

const myObject = getTotalResponses();
console.log(myObject.totalOutboxes);
```

Comment: when I try `console.log(myObject.totalOutboxes)` I don't see anything in my `VSCode` terminal?

Comment: Your object may be named differently or your code/IDE configured differently.

Comment: would having the function as `async` could be the reason I don't see the value?